# Pathname string issues for React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm having a problem with getting files to load properly in Node JS depending on how the pathname is stored.

```
{
  Object.entries(LEGEND).map(([key, value]) => {
    return (
      <div key={"layout-editor-element-" + key}>
        <Card
          className="text-center"
          align="center"
          tag="a"
          title={value.desc}
          onClick={() => this.generateItem(key)}
        >
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Img
              variant="top"
              src={require(`../assets/icons/simpleText-Icon.png`)}
              className="card-images"
            />
            <Card.Text>{value.title}</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Works fine, but changing to

```
<Card.Img variant="top" src={require (value.iconName)}
```

Gets me a console error

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../assets/icons/simpleText-Icon.png'

The other values in map load in fine, and even when I declare something like

```
const pathname = "../assets/icons/simpleText-Icon.png"
```

and then use

```
<Card.Img variant="top" src={require(pathname)} className="card-images"/>
```

I get the same error.

Its the same pathname string, but clearly something changes when you try to substitute in constants, though I'm baffled on what it could be.

Is there anyone with an idea, or some workaround/alternative way I can get it to load images selectively based on the map?

Answer (score 0):

The packager can't handle dynamic require's.

What you can do to fix this though is instead of storing the string `../assets/icons/simpleText-Icon.png` inside of `value.iconName`, you can store the full require expression as the key's value:

```
iconName: require('../assets/icons/simpleText-Icon.png')
```